# present perfect preceding past simple (Over the past 3 days, it has rained a lot however it became sunny)

Tags: tense

I have made up the example below.

(ex) Over the past three days, it has rained a lot; however, it became sunny this morning. Tonight, it's raining again.

In my example, I have the present perfect (has rained) to relate to the time frame (over the past three days) before the next event in the past simple (became sunny).

Does my example make sense when the present perfect precedes the past simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. "Over the past three days" is a period *which can extend to the present*, which is one reason for choosing the perfect.

The fact that there was a portion of that period when it was sunny does not invalidate that choice.